# HTML - Pattern for more words

Tags: javascript, html, forms, design-patterns

I have an input text and i want to put a pattern to use only characters without numbers for name. 
I was trying with this but doesn't work. If i write the name he alert me to type the name.

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<b>Persoana de contact</b><font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}" class="form-control" name="contact" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Adaugati va rugam numele persoanei de contact.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
<button type = submit>Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You want the pattern to match more than one character I assume? `[A-Za-z]{3,}` means at least three.

Comment: I want when i type for example "John Castle" to be a valid pattern. When i do this he say me "Please match the requested format." I edit the code from my post. When you run it you will se he still give you the alert.

Comment: You haven't included the space character in the pattern. Add `\s` inside the square brackets.

Comment: Ohh..this was! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<b>Persoana de contact</b><font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{3,}" class="form-control" name="contact" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Adaugati va rugam numele persoanei de contact.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
<button type = submit>Send</button>
</form>
```

Was solved! Thanks to Chris G.

The changes to pattern are "pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{3,}". This will help you to type with space bettwen the words and respect the pattern.